# Django Models Reverse Lookup

Tags: python, django

I am trying to normalize my models in Django. I have three models as below

```
from django.db import models

class Province(models.Model):
    province = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return province

class District(models.Model):
    district = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    province = models.ForeignKey('Province', related_name='district_province', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return district

class School(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    district = models.ForeignKey('District', related_name='school_district', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school
```

When I query the school model I can get the District, My question is, is it possible to also get the province without adding it as a foreign key in the School model? if yes, how do I achieve that?

The Use cases are:

1. Query a school with all its properties including district and province.

With: `School.objects.all` or `School.objects.get/filter` I can get all schools and the district details but I do not know how to reach the province model.

2. Get all schools in a District

With: `School.objects.filter(district=x)` I can get schools in a district with no problem here.

3. Get all schools in a Province

Say I have province ID as 2, how do I get all schools in province 2?

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar challenge this is what I am using:

```
data = School.objects.filter(district__province__id=2)
```

In the filter params, district__province__x gives me access to the Province model and I can filter by any column in that model.